# Display Firebase data inside PickerView

Tags: swift, firebase, uipickerview

**CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED AND IS WORKING AS EXPECTED**

I have a View Controller with a text field and a PickerView. I want to display the data i have stored in Firebase inside the PickerView. I'm able to retrieve and print the data from Firebase but I can't find a way to display it inside the PickerView. Here is my code:

```
  import UIKit
    import Firebase

class pickerVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var labelTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoPickerViewer: UIPickerView!

    var dbRef: CollectionReference!
    var pickerView: UIPickerView?
    var itemsClass = [ItemInfo]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        infoPickerViewer.delegate = self
        infoPickerViewer.dataSource = self

        dbRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(ITEMS_REF)

        labelTxt.inputView = pickerView
        labelTxt.delegate = self

        self.infoPickerViewer = pickerView
        self.infoPickerViewer?.delegate = self
        self.infoPickerViewer?.dataSource = self

        self.infoPickerViewer.reloadAllComponents()
        getItems()

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

      func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            labelTxt = textField
        }

        func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
                self.pickerView?.reloadAllComponents()
                return true
        }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if labelTxt.isFirstResponder {
            return self.itemsClass.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            if labelTxt.isFirstResponder {
                return itemsClass[row].itemName
            }
            return nil
        }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            if labelTxt.isFirstResponder {
                let item = itemsClass[row].itemName
                labelTxt.text = item
            }
        }


    func getItems() {
        dbRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("error fetching docs: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.infoPickerViewer.reloadAllComponents()
                let snap = snapshot
                for document in snap!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let itemCode = data[ITEMS_CODE] as? String ?? ""
                    let itemName = data[ITEMS_NAME] as? String ?? ""

                    let t = ItemInfo(itemCode: itemCode, itemName: itemName)

                    self.itemsClass.append(t)

                    print("ITEMS_CODE", itemCode as Any)
                    print("ITEMS_NAME", itemName as Any)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Firebase DB is structured as follow:

```
              collection/AutoID/itemCode: "item1"
                                itemName: "item2"

              collection/AutoID/itemCode: "item3"
                                itemName: "item4"
```

I only need to display the itemName inside the PickerView, the itemCode I'm going to use it to run a query depending on the selection in the PickerView.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typically, tableViews, collectionViews etc are backed by a dataSource which is generally an array. As the code in the question sits, it's not doing anything with the data retrieved from Firestore other than printing it. That data needs to be added to a class array (`items`) and when complete, update your UI. You're probably going to want to craft a class to store the individual documents from Firestore, perhaps an `ItemClass` and then the `items` array would contain those ItemClass objects; `var items = [ItemClass]()`. e.g. your code doesn't work because it's incomplete.

Comment: @Jay, thank you for your comment. Your answer was correct, i had to create a Class to hold those items. I have updated the original code with the final version. Everything is working as expected.